# installing drupal in my already developed site

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, content-management-system

i have a doubt about Drupal, i've recently developed a [website](http://www.ferreteriaprogresemos.com) using php and mysql, this site has a cms that was created by the previous developer, so... i have some new contents in the DB and i need to create the modules in the cms to manage them, but i've heard that it would be better if i install drupal. ¿Can i install this drupal cms and manage my already created DB?, i'm not using a drupal theme. I mean i only need to manage the DB not create the entire site. ¿is it possible? or it would be better just create the new modules into the already created cms (it isn't joomla, wordpress...) ¡thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to install Drupal and use it to manage the existing site.  They are going to have different data structures.

If you came to understand the data structures of the two CMSes you might find that you could export out of the old one and into Drupal.  This would require a good bit of comfort with MySQL.

Comment: ok thanks! it would be better just add the new modules to the same cms, i just need to add, edit or delete data in the DB, anyway the site is already developed, and start again can be kind of annoying... ¡thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the existing db and can build custom module to use the data in other table, created for your custom CMS. However, there is no direct or automatic way which will allow you to access those data! You have to write your own code!